# Why do ICO startups mostly prefer ERC20 tokens for raising funds?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, erc-20, tokens, ico

Can anyone create ERC20 tokens on their own? Does it need any technical expertise? Provide whatever information you know relevant to this question. It will be helpful even for newbies who are visiting here

Comment: It's called [path dependence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_dependence).

Answer (score 0):

ERC20 tokens are more or less just smart contract (piece of code), which stores balances. It's a fairly simple contract that anyone can then deploy to an EVM-compatible chain (such as Ethereum). Even if you do not know how to code, you can use tools like OZ's wizzard: https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/wizard which generates ERC20 token with desired options.

Now to answer your question, Ethereum has a vast range of investors and a strong community, so it's easier to launch and sell out an ICO there than for example on Hedera.